# Why it doesn't work (string array)?

Tags: android, arrays, string

Hi I wanted to add new string to string array by this method but it doesn't work, because when I start new activity, then favaorites array isn't updated. Why ?

```
Resources res = getResources();
    String[] favorites = res.getStringArray(R.array.favorites);
    String[] planets = res.getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
    String[] temp = new String[favorites.length+1];
    System.arraycopy(favorites,0,temp,0,favorites.length);
    temp[favorites.length] = planets[mCounter];
    favorites = temp;
```

Comment: You need to provide more information. Where are you displaying this string array? Aside from mCounter being an unknown value, the code is okay. How do you know favorites has not updated? What have you tried?

Comment: mCounter is a seekbar progress and it isn't an unkown value. I guess that it doesn't work because favorites don't change in file after finish activity and when I start activity which is using favorites array there is no strings except of one which I saved there manually.

Comment: Is there a way to save this array permanently in strings ?

Comment: resources files cannot be changed in android. copy favorites String array in someother array and work on it.

Answer (score 0):

In your case what you can do is use SharedPreferences to store the string into it. No array assigns requires and it is a much cleaner way to do it. Some links to get you started:

1. http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2009/10/shared-preferences-android-developer.html
2. http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2009/10/shared-preferences-android-developer.html
3. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem, you should be create an SQLite Database that houses all these properties. Then you should retrieve them from the Cursor (after you query your database) and use the results as necessary

Also another note is that you **CANNOT** add to the already defined R.array.* because its a precompiled resource.